# How can I increase a partition's size?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

On my laptop I have Ubuntu 11.10 and Windows 7 in dual boot mode.

I made a partition of 30 GB for Ubuntu but now it's too small and I want to increase this disk size from 32 GB to 100 GB.

This is home my disk looks like:

```
C Drive - 360 GB
D Drive - 200 GB
E Drive - 80 GB
```

On the F Drive I installed Ubuntu which contains 30 GB.

How can I increase this partition from 30 GB to 100 GB?

Someone suggested [Gpart](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) tool to achiveve this. but there is a risk to lose my Windows or Ubuntu install.

Comment: Boot off the live cd/usb, and resize it with gparted, you can't do it while in Ubuntu as you can't resize mounted partitions.

Comment: @UriHerrera Boot off means? and here i have to compulsary use gpart tool?

Comment: Means you create a liveusb and insert it into your computer and boot from it, and yes you *have* to use gparted

Answer (score 10):

As suggested, you can boot from a live CD or USB into Ubuntu. Then open the application *gparted* which will already be present and resize partitions. This can however break your bootloader and might require fixing it.

A better idea is to make a new partition, and move your home directory there so that you have the additional space and Ubuntu partition can be reserved for Ubuntu.

Here are the steps to do that.

1. Boot from a live CD or USB into Ubuntu
2. Run *gparted* to shrink or delete a current windows partition (if you delete E, for example, remember to backup the files in E from inside Windows). Shrinking a partition will not delete any of your files, but backup is a good idea.
3. Create a new ext4 partition in the empty space
4. Follow [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving) guide to move your home there

Note:Please don't forget to remove (or comment or edit) old  /dev/sda3 in /etc/fstab. Because multiple declaration of volume (such as  existing /dev/sda3   ntfs    and     /dev/sda3    ext4)  would be crash your ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

1. As @Uri suggests, boot from Ubuntu Live CD and use gparted to remove/shrink "E drive", then move and resize the Ubuntu partition to take the free space. Since Ubuntu partition is the last on the disk, you'll have to move its origin which will break Ubuntu's bootloader - gparted's website contains instructions on how to fix this.
2. If you're worried about deleting/moving partitions with gparted, you can just convert one of the partitions (your "E drive") to ext4 and either mount it as /home or symlink it instead or somewhere inside your home directory. The 30 gb partition will then be used for system files and the other partition for your documents and stuff.

Comment: Thanks a lot in second option how can i achive this tell me some stepts what i have to do in this. i will find more details from google . but can u please help me to to figureout first few steps.

Comment: In first Option Gparted is readymade tool? i have to download this?

Comment: please see @knivor's answer for detailed instructions

Answer (score 1):

Shutdown your computer, place the Ubuntu CD/USB in it. Then restart your computer and boot from CD/USB and start using *Gpart* tool.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Thank you for your answer. The OP could benefit from a slightly more _detailed_ answer. It would be nice if you could add more detail.

Answer (score 0):

you want to add more space to F Drive, so you can use Disk Management to SHRINK D Drive about 70gb, and EXTEND the 70gb to F Drive.

Also, you can use some tools like MiniTool Partition to manage it. First, you can EXTEND D Drive directly to add 70gb to F Drive. OR you can use RESIZE/MOVE function to get unallocated space from E Drive. Next, MERGE F Drive with Unallocated partition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `gparted` to use it. For example:

```
$ sudo apt install gparted
```

and then run it as root. For example:

```
# gparted
```

or

```
$ sudo gparted
```

if you have `sudo` privileges.