# Steps to take before resizing partition to prevent damaging data

Tags: 11.10, partitioning, home-directory, swap

I use Ubuntu 11.10 and have three partitions, one ext4 for the root directory, one ext4 for the /home and one for swap.

I need to release disk space so I can increase swap space, and create a new partition for a Windows installation (meh, but it's a need for work stuff like visual studio).

So I was thinking about resizing the /home partition (taking off 50Gbs of about 60Gb free it has) but I'm kinda afraid of things going wrong and losing /home data in this operation.

So, what things should I do to increase safety? (I'm not in conditions to make a proper backup right now).

Comment: Well, using a physical partition has the advantage of being able to boot directly and inside ubuntu using a virtualization tool. And I'll need to resize it at least to increase my swap area anyway

Comment: Agreed, was just wondering about it :)

Comment: In fact, I was experiencing some performance problems with using windows as a vm, and a physical partition sounded like a reasonable solution (cheaper than buying new hardware)

Comment: Please go thru this QA

It may be useful 

http://askubuntu.com/questions/102733/how-can-i-increase-a-partitions-size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data loss is rare when resizing a partition, but obviously can happen. I an not aware of anything you can do to reduce the risk, rather I advise you back up your data first (a working backup is always a good idea anyways).