# Extend partition with unallocated space

Tags: partitioning, mint

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I increase a partition's size?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102733/how-can-i-increase-a-partitions-size)

My linux partition is 18 gigabytes.

I managed to shrink 7 gigs of other partition.

Now i want to add those 7 gigs to the linux partition.

With my disk utility, its not possible.

Is there another way to do this?