# How to get al the disk space for ubuntu 12.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, windows-xp

Recently I changed for Linux Ubuntu 12.04, I left Windows and I want now to get all my hard disk space, cause when I formatted my PC installing Ubuntu 12.04, I only gave Ubuntu `23.0 GB` and now I'm only using Ubuntu 12.04 and I want to get all my hard disk space (Before called Windows; hard drive C and Hard Drive D).

How can I do this? Do I have to use terminal? Thanks  .

Answer (score 1):

See, as this was asked, and has been asked many times before, you are likely to get what you want by performing a simple search. However, here is one such question

[How can I increase a partition's size?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102733/how-can-i-increase-a-partitions-size)

When you view a question, there is a list of Related Questions on the right sidebar. Taking a look through those is also generally useful if the current question does not give you the result.

Comment: Searching must be really hard and time-consuming. :P