# How to extend the Size of my Ubuntu Partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I have Installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my pre-installed Windows8 sony laptop with HDD of 500Gb.

There are a few partitions present by default like recovery ,etc.

I have created a few other partitions of 200 GB and 100 GB on `/dev/sda7` and `/dev/sda8` respectively. My Windows 8 is installed on `/dev/sda5` while I have installed Ubuntu on `/dev/sda11` with swap on `/dev/sda12`.

Now, I want to shrink my Windows 8 drive which is 109 GB and extend the Ubuntu partition of 15 GB by using the unallocated space from the earlier drive.

I tried using GParted via LiveUSB and performing the `SWAP-OFF` but I was unsuccessful.

Please suggest me a way ASAP.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I increase a partition's size?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/102733/how-can-i-increase-a-partitions-size)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should better be careful about the following:

1. If you really need to shrink the Windows (7/8) operating system
   partition, try and do this operation using its own Disk Management
   Tool in order to avoid Windows booting problems.
2. It seems you have a number of (max. 4) Primary Partitions, at least
   1 of which is an Extended Partition, which in turn includes any
   number of Logical Partitions, and this makes the things a little
   more complicated if any one of the partitions you want to
   shrink/expand is inside such an Extended Partition while the other
   is outside. In such a case, you should carefully look at the order
   of partitions in GParted to make sure that you create the
   Unallocated Space at the correct end and then and move it at the
   correct direction so that you can follow the correct route to get
   into and out of the Extended Partition and then to join with the
   other (Primary) partition or vice versa.