# Ubuntu telling me I need more Space

Tags: filesystem

Ok, I downloaded Ubuntu 13.10, for a eMachines G640 with 64-bit AMD-processor, making it dual-boot with Windows 7 with a USB not CD.

Didn't had problem installing it, booted nicely into Ubuntu but when I transferred some files from my 1TB External-HDD, to my PCs 320GB Hard-drive, I got the error message saying *"there is only 103,3 GB space left"* and told me to *"delete some files to get more space"*.

What's the problem, and how do I fix it? is it the partition? the OS? My PC?

EDIT: Right, a friend of mine said it is the partition, and I should extend the Ubuntu Partition, because he says it's only 20GB out of the 320GB hard-drive, and he doesn't know how to do that. Help.

the partitions are set up like this.

```
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc615c615

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    27650047    13824000   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda2   *    27650048    27854847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        27854848   580299634   276222393+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       580302846   625141759    22419457    5  Extended
Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5       580302848   619380735    19538944   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       619382784   625141759     2879488   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Disc usage

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5        19G   18G     0 100% /
none            4,0K     0  4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            1,4G  4,0K  1,4G   1% /dev
tmpfs           276M  1,2M  275M   1% /run
none            5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none            1,4G  156K  1,4G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   40K  100M   1% /run/user
```

Thanks, Dash_plus_Java for the instructions you gave me.

It really helped me out a lot. Hoof-pump /)

Comment: Can you add the output of this command to your question please? Open terminal and run `sudo fdisk -l` . This will show us how your system partitions are set up.

Comment: so this is how your partitions are set up: sda1(Hidden Windows): 13Gb, sda2(Windows System): 100Mb, sda3(Windows 7): 269Gb, sda5(Ubuntu): 19Gb, sda6(Swap): 2Gb. sda4 just contains your Ubuntu partition and swap. It looks like you have about 20 Gb of space for Ubuntu on your computer. Did you set up the partitions manually? 20Gb is enough to run Ubuntu, but not enough to be copying over media files to it.

Comment: You need to shrink the `/dev/sda3` partition then extend the Ubuntu partition (`/dev/sda5`). See here for more info: http://askubuntu.com/questions/102733/how-can-i-increase-a-partitions-size

Comment: what is the output of `mount`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for giving me some more information to work with Bent. If you want to give more space to Ubuntu than 20Gb you will have to shrink the size of your Windows 7 partition. This can ruin your Windows 7 install easily; so if you haven't already **Back Up Your Files!**

First, you want to be sure that you have enough unused space in Windows that you can shrink the partition without causing problems. In Windows open the explorer and check the properties of the C: drive. If the drive has enough unused space to give up then move to the next step. Otherwise, remove files until you have enough space.

Second, run a disk defragment on Windows. This will group up all the files so it will be easier to move them if they must be moved when resizing.

Third, boot up a Ubuntu live DvD/USB and run Gparted. This program will let you resize the partitions on your computer. Right click on the swap partition on the very right and select `swap-off`. This will let you work with the partitions.

Right click on the large Windows 7 partition and select `resize`. Subtract the space you wan to give to Ubuntu from this partition.

Right click on sda4 and select resize. drag it to the left so that there is no gap between partitions. Now resize sda5 (Ubuntu) and do the same.

Once everything is done click the green check mark to apply the operations.

Cross your fingers. If everything worked you should now have the extras space on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you have a massive hard drive (something about 1.5-2TB), and Ubuntu is simply calculating the percentage that is left in the filesystem (5-10%) and issue an alert because the space is exhausting. For now you can ignore the message (or ask to do not show it again). There isn't a way to "solve" it (I look up the dconf keys and the preference was nowhere to be found, maybe hard coded).