# Extending my Root Paritition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, gparted

I've Win8/Ubuntu Dual boot. I already have 4 partition so i cannot create a new partition and mount it elsewhere. So, this ([How can I increase a partition's size?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102733/how-can-i-increase-a-partitions-size)) question did not help.

Here's a screen shot of my Gparted (run on Ubuntu Live)
[image]

How can I extend `/dev/sda6`  so that  i can make use of unallocated space ? 
(w/o failing my current grub)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to move the unallocated space just above to the `/dev/sda2` so that you can get the unallocated space into the extended partition.

Follow the below steps to increase the size of `/root` partition and make sure that you had not mounted any partitions,

- Boot Ubuntu live disk and open gparted partition editor.
- Now right-click on the `/dev/sda3`    partition and select Resize/Move option.Now move the dragger to the extreme right so that the unallocated space will comes above the `/dev/sda3` partition.
- Follow the above step to move the unallocated space just above to the `/dev/sda2`.
- Now right-click on the extended partition and select the Resize/Move option.Now you can be able to add the unallocated space to the extended partition.
- After adding that,the space comes just below to the `/dev/sda6`.
- Now right-click on the `/dev/sda6` partition and select Resize/Move option to add the unallocated space to your `/root` partition.

Comment: What is the expected time to complete that?

Comment: within 15 mins.