# Reinstall Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I am using Ubuntu alongside Windows 7. And my system does not allow me to part my disk more than 4 partition. And I want to delete Ubuntu and reinstall it again. But this case I want to give it more space and swap space. How can I do this correctly and without risk.

Comment: duplicated http://askubuntu.com/questions/404361/extending-my-root-paritition

Answer (score 2):

You should use an extended partition in place of your current partitions for Ubuntu and swap. Inside that extended partition, you will be able to have multiple logical partitions.

**To avoid risks:** Do a backup of **all** your data, that means backup **all** partitions, including those you intend to leave unchanged! Manipulating the partition scheme is always subject to possible data loss. A good program for editing partitions is gparted. There is also a live CD version of it.

If possible, try to avoid MBR partition tables. Instead, use a GPT, which doesn't have the limitations of MBR partitioned volumes. This is possible on all computers with EFI and on some computers with BIOS (check manual of your mainboard first). **Be aware:** Windows 7 might refuse to install on a GPT partition if you have a BIOS computer, even if your computer actually can boot off it!

If you want to reinstall Ubuntu and you want to use the same version of it, first write the installed packages to a file using this command:

`dpkg --get-selections | grep -v ^lib > file`

Save this file on a safe place like a USB flash memory. Libraries are excluded, because apt will resolve required dependencies on its own.

Once you reinstalled Ubuntu, issue these commands:

`apt-get install dselect && dselect access && dselect update
cat file | dpkg --set-selections
apt-get dselect-upgrade`

Then you should have a system with the same software installed as you had before. After that it might be clever to restore some files in /etc of your Ubuntu backup.