# Expand root partition without formatting

Tags: partitioning, root, format

I would really like a clear guide to expand my root (/) partition. The screenshot shows my partitions (Windows 7/Ubuntu 14.04 - dual boot) and as you can see `/dev/sda3` is my Ubuntu partition. I would like to move the 90 GB unallocated partition up to the root and expand the root.  I would appreciate help with the following questions:

1. Can I freely resize the data partition (`/dev/sda5`) until it has no more unused space?
2. Can I even extend the root without formatting it?
3. Can I unmount (so that i may move the 90 GB up) the home partition without bad stuff happening?

My partions:

[image]

Thank you very much in advance! Semester begins soon and I have like 10 GB of courseware to fit into the *root* dir.

Comment: Here is your answer. http://askubuntu.com/questions/492054/how-to-extend-my-root-partition. But your thread seems possible duplicate thread.

Comment: Thanks alot, I already looked at this post and it deletes the swap partition. I can do that but I don't think I can delete my home and boot partition (well maybe the latter).

Comment: Deleting home and boot partition? But you were mentioned extending only the partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No
2. Yes
3. Yes

All the above answers are only true if you've booted from the [GParted Live CD](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) or the Live Ubuntu CD (with which you've installed Ubuntu)

Comment: Thank you, I'll give that a try and see how it goes. Regarding point 1.: How much space can I take for the data partition  (/dev/sda5) (a relatively empty partition to be used for music).

Comment: I would say: if you take double of whatever data you have now, you shouls be safe enough! ;) And as you're a reputation 1 user: don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "1" at the left of this text, therefore "accepting" the answer, which is better then saying "thank you" as your and my reputation will go up...

Comment: Still though - words are nice: Thanks for your help man appreciate it <3