# Resize2fs: The filesystem is already blocks long. Nothing to do!

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I'm trying to resize my root partition of Ubuntu 14.04. Referring to the answer here:[How to extend my root (/) partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492054/how-to-extend-my-root-partition), I did the following:

1. Boot from live usb
2. Shrink a volume using Gparted, apply all operations
3. Run `sudo resize2fs /dev/sda10`

I got the following output:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo resize2fs /dev/sda10
resize2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
The filesystem is already 2857216 blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

Gparted screenshot looks like this:

[image]

I want to add the 19.81GB unallocated space after /dev/sda11 to /dev/sda10. What should I do? (I have Ubuntu 14.04 on dual boot with Windows 8.1.)

Comment: You have to move sda11 "to the right side" and then you can extend sda10. Don't forget the backup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to run anything from the command line as gparted takes care of this all for you.  Simply resize the partition in gparted.  You will first need to move sda11 over so that the free space follows sda10 before you can grow it.

Comment: Nothing to add!  Upvoted!  ;-)