# Disk allocation

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, gparted, ext4

I installed ubuntu 15.04 and used entire space(640 GiB) for ext4 partition but now it is showing that **used space = 30.91 GiB**, **free space = 24.96 GiB** and **536.40 GiB unallocated space**. I tried to extend the space of file system using **Gparted** but its not working. So could any one please tell me how can I extend or allocate the space.
[image]

output after command

> sudo parted -l

[image]

Gparted is not showing option for resize thats the problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of the terminal command `sudo parted -l`. That will probably give us more information than your screenshot...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extend my root (/) partition?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/492054/how-to-extend-my-root-partition)

Comment: ^ In my case, I am not able to resize my /dev/sda1 parting as its clear in snapshot though I don't know the reason behind this. And before posting this I went through that answer.

Comment: Who is showing "536.40 GiB unallocated space". It seems `sda1` is already maxed out at around 636GB but there is conflicting evidence about that. Something is weird. There is a red icon on /dev/sda1 in gparted. what does it says when you right-click on it ?

Comment: after right click its showing only four options 
1. resize/move
2. unmount
3. Manage flags
4. info.

Answer (score 0):

You can allocate the free space (with GParted) by Right-Clicking it > New. Set its new space to 536.4 GB, label it and create the new partition. Apply the action by clicking that green V under the Device tab. Then you will be able to create an extended partition.

Comment: after right click its showing only four options 
1. resize/move
2. unmount
3. Manage flags
4. info.

Comment: You are making something wrong. Do not right-click the partition, right-click the non-allocated space.

Comment: Agree, but its not showing unallocated space exclusively.

Comment: So you do not see any unallocated space? Only your partition with less space?

Comment: yes, Only partition with less space