# Slow boot time after resizing partitions. Editing fstab did not work

Tags: boot, xubuntu, fstab, partitioning

I am having problems similar to those described in [Boot much slower after partition resize](https://askubuntu.com/questions/643352/boot-much-slower-after-partition-resize). To summarise I repartitioned my hard drive to get more space in `/`. To do this I deleted the swap space, resized and then repartitioned swap. Everything went cleanly except when trying to boot it takes about 1-2 minutes to get the login screen.

As suggested in these other posts:

1. [Deleted Swap, now boot takes forever](https://askubuntu.com/questions/625072/deleted-swap-now-boot-takes-forever)
2. [Really slow boot on 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760694/really-slow-boot-on-16-04)

I checked the `blkid` outputs with those in `/etc/fstab` and edited it so they match. This did not solve the long boot times though. Any suggestions?

Further Info:

`systemd-analyze`

`Startup finished in 8.469s (kernel) + 3min 351ms (userspace) = 3min 8.820s`

Output from `systemd-analyze blame` is [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23405395/)

Uninteresting output from `cat /etc/rc.local` is [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23405424/)

Output from `cat /var/log/boot.log` is [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23405433/)

[fstab](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23409042/)

`sudo blkid` [output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23409046/)

Comment: Please run these two commands in a terminal and post the outputs here: `systemd-analyze` and `systemd-analyze blame`

Comment: `systemd-analyze`:
Startup finished in 8.469s (kernel) + 3min 351ms (userspace) = 3min 8.820s
`systemd-analyze blame`:
 http://paste.ubuntu.com/23405395/

Comment: Can you post the contents of the file /etc/rc.local and /var/log/boot.log?

Comment: `cat /etc/rc.local`:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/23405424/   
`cat /var/log/boot.log` :  http://paste.ubuntu.com/23405433/

Comment: Yes. the UUID for `/` `/home` and swap partitions match the output to `blkid`. Though there is nothing beneath
`#/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0`
`#/dev/mapper/cryptswap2 none swap sw 0 0`
in the fstab file. I am not sure what these even are.

Comment: OK, I guess the problem is this: The swap is encrypted, and now repartitioning has made the configurations for swap encryption incorrect. Now, disable cryptswap2: `cryptsetup remove cryptswap2`, remove the line in `/etc/fstab` containing cryptswap2 then reboot. Create the swap and encrypt it again.

Comment: If that still doesn't solve the problem, try the suggestions in the answers to this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/711016/slow-boot-a-start-job-is-running-for-dev-disk-by

Comment: Okay sure thing.  Should I also remove cryptswap1? Thanks for all your help.

Comment: According to the file `/var/log/boot.log`, there was no problem with cryptswap1, maybe because you didn't touch it, so I think you don't have to remove it.

Comment: Do you want/need encrypted swap? Post the output of `cat /etc/fstab` and `sudo blkid`, and a screenshot of gparted /dev/sda.

Comment: I am not sure what encrypted swap does, so I probably don't need it (thought that might be very ignorant). The outputs are,

Comment: The outputs are, `cat /etc/fstab`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23409042/
`sudo blkid`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23409046/

Comment: @lackos In future please [edit] further info into your post as comments can be deleted for a number of reasons and may even go unread.

Comment: Related: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=215914

Comment: Sorry, I'll keep that in mind for next time. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: @lackos It would be great if you have a hint for me on a [similar issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/496298/slow-boot-time-after-cloning-disk-and-resizing-partitions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up fixing it by removing `/etc/crypttab` as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/711016/slow-boot-a-start-job-is-running-for-dev-disk-by) (link courtesy of PyGeek03). However it was still booting slowly until I commented out the crpytswap line in `fstab`. After this it booted up at normal speeds. Just for reference here is my new fstab file,

[fstab](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23413921/)

Thanks again for everyone's help and suggestions.