# How can I resize my / partition?

Tags: partitioning

[image]

I want to increase the size of /dev/sda1 by using the size of unallocated space.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extend my root (/) partition?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/492054/how-to-extend-my-root-partition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In GParted:

1. Right click on sda3, choose Resize/Move and slide it completely to the right.
2. Right click on sda1, choose Resize/Move and resize it fitting the unallocated space.

Comment: I would suggest to include "swapoff" too :)