# How to extend root partition volume using GParted on 14.04?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I recently received a notification after the latest updates (Ubuntu 14.04.4) that I am running out of space on my root folder. I performed `sudo apt-get clean`but the space freed doesn't seem to be enough (1.5 GB free). Therefore I am looking to add another 50 GB to my `/` folder. I have freed 50 GB using my Windows Disk Management which now shows as "unallocated" (below `sda4`) on my Gparted:

[image: my GParted]

Is there any way to integrate this free space with my root folder while I'm online? If not, is/are there (an) alternative(s) to what has been suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492054/how-to-extend-my-root-partition)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: you may move other partition and grow the root partition and another way is to cut and paste the partition on unallocate space but risk is ever, first take backup, All the best and `Please share the result`

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you will have to shift all the partitions that are located to the left of your root partition to the left, to in the end create a 50 GB space at the left of your root partition. You cannot bridge two partitions if you are asking that.

Mind you that this will take a long time, and may result in data loss if the operation is interrupted.

Please backup this data if possible.

Best of Luck to you!!!

Comment: There is however, another thing you can do: you can make a disk image through the disks application and then apply this image to a newly created partition in the 50GB space. This will save time. Then you can run boot-repair to update your GRUB from a live USB.