# I want to resize my root partition but when I run gparted my root partition does not appear

Tags: partitioning, gparted

Not a duplicate of [How to extend my root (/) partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492054/how-to-extend-my-root-partition). That example the reporter can see his root partition. I cannot.
I want to resize my root partition to make it bigger but when I run gparted the root partition does not appear.
In the screenshot below my root is called /dev/sdb1 but that does not appear on gparted. The other ones do however. Also when I boot using a boot disc and type df then the root partition is called cow.

Can anyone help me to solve this please.

[image: State of my partitions]

Ok So this is my real problem.
I cannot seem to allocate more space to my root partition because as  @ByteCommander pointed out I need to select that partition from the top right but when I do that it is the only partition on the screen as you can see from my picture below. So how can I move space from one partition to the next if there is none available  before or after it?

[My root partition on its own which I cannot get any space allocated to as I have no partitions either before or after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iEPL.png)

Comment: Not a duplicate. That example the reporter can see his root partition. I cannot.

Comment: O.k. retracting my close vote. But you may be prone to that someone else will flag that as well, you should make that clear in your question and maybe link to that one I referenced too.

Comment: Are you doing it in the Live CD / USB session? The file system needs to be unmounted to be able to manipulate it.

Comment: There's a drop-down menu in the top right corner of the Gparted window which lets you pick the disk it displays. Default is `/dev/sda`, so you probably just have to pick `/dev/sdb` in there.

Comment: Thanks @ByteCommander I found it :)  But It still wont let me increase the partition no matter what i try including the instructions in this http://askubuntu.com/questions/492054/how-to-extend-my-root-partition

Comment: Did you boot from a live disk? You have to boot from a live system and unmount all mounted partitions of the disk you want to edit (`/dev/sdb`). The live disk will automatically use available swap partitions, so you must tell it not to use that manually in Gparted. Simply right-click on all used partitions and select "Unmount" or "Swapoff".

Comment: If your partition is called cow, maybe you could install cowsay package: `sudo apt-get install cowsay`. See some examples here: http://www.binarytides.com/linux-fun-commands/. Perhaps not particularly useful to your situation, but it could release some of the tension and the frustration.