# Remove swap and add space to another partition

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, swap, format, fdisk

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 Server without GUI.
I would like to remove the swap and add the diskspace to my root partition.

How can I do this? Both partitions are ext4 (no lvm)

Comment: Can you share the output of fdisk-l and df-h.

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/492054/how-to-extend-my-root-partition).