# Unallocated space to Ubuntu

Tags: disk

How would I go about if I wanted to extend my Ubuntu disk? This currently my disk:

[image: GParted screenshot]

I would like to change the "Unallocated" to `/dev/sda6` where Ubuntu is. I've currently swapped off the `linux-swap`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Answer (score 1):

Simply choose your `/` partition ( dev/sda6 ) and click on resize and add some of the unallocated space to there the tool GParted is perfect for that. Since Linux kernel version 2.6 you can resize `/` even without reboot, but If the unallocated space comes before `/`, then you will have to **boot from a Live CD or USB** and **move your `/` to somewhere before the unallocated space**. To make a Live CD or USB you can use the "Startup Disk Creator" utility which comes pre-installed on Ubuntu.

---

You can also have a look at this more detailed question/answer:

[How to extend my root (/) partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492054/how-to-extend-my-root-partition)

Comment: Can't resize since the space comes *before* the partition.

Answer (score 0):

You can't extend the partition because the unallocated space comes before `/`, so you have to move the partition to the left, and then you can expand it.  The partition must not be in use to do this, so you have to boot from a Live CD or Live USB. To create one you can, for example, use the pre-installed utility "Startup Disk Creator".