# Filesystem shows /dev/nvme0n1p1 instead of /dev/sda

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, mount, windows-10

I installed a dual boot of Ubuntu 16.04 (Windows being my other OS) two months ago to try it out. I want to allot more space to it on my hard drive. I was looking up tutorials, and I noticed that my filesystem names don't look anything like those in the tutorials. For example:

```
df -h
```

outputs:

[image: output]

How would I allot more space to Ubuntu (in layman's terms)?

Comment: Note that the title of your question is misleading. Although your disk device is simply named differently from the usual, that's *not* a problem. `/dev/sd{x}` is the name used by most conventional disks (spinning hard disks) and SSDs that connect via the SATA bus and in some other ways. The `/dev/nvme...` device name indicates newer NVMe "disks." On the partition table level, they're treated in the same way -- you must simply identify them with a different name.

Comment: Follow same tutorials. NVMe just means that you've gotba specific type of solid state drive

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This is normal if you have your disk connected through an [NVM Express](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NVM_Express) port instead of e.g. a traditional SATA port.

So just imagine in your case `/dev/nvme0n1` being equivalent to `/dev/sda` and e.g. `/dev/nvme0n1p6` (which is your `/` root partition) being equivalent to something like `/dev/sda6`.

Other than the naming, there should be no notable difference when it comes to simple partitioning operations like growing your root partition. Just follow the guide [How to extend my root (/) partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492054/how-to-extend-my-root-partition) with your appropriate disk and partition names.

By the way, the command `lsblk` or `lsblk -f` can help you a lot to get a quick overview of your disk and partitioning structure and to look up the device names.

Comment: in AWS, I connected 2 two 300 GB drives at `/dev/sdh` and `/dev/sdm`. the nvme numbers are `nvme3n1` and `nvme5n1`. How do I identify which drive is linked to which number?

Comment: @HimanshuBansal Hi, comments are not a suitable place to ask for subthreads. Just create a new thread with your own issue to get help.