# Why is the hard drive no longer called dev/sda?

Tags: gparted

I have a brand new laptop with a brand new install of Ubuntu 18.10 and I am very pleased with both the machine and the OS.

One thing, however is bothering me: Under gparted my main hard drive (an SSD actually) is labelled  `/dev/nvme0n1p1` (the EFI partition) and `/dev/nvme0n1p2` (the Ubuntu partition) rather than `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda2` in all of the other releases of Ubuntu I have used before. Also a mounted SD card is shown in gparted as `/dev/mmcblk0p1` rather that `/dev/sdb`.

Why the new, hard to remember, labels?

Comment: Refer to this thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/932331/filesystem-shows-dev-nvme0n1p1-instead-of-dev-sda

Comment: Your particular type of SSD requires different driver ( because it is different SSD technology ) Hence nvme naming

Comment: Simply put, neither /dev/nvme..., not /dev/mmc... are harddrives, so it is only logical to call them different names.

Comment: @mikewhatever /dev/nvm or /dev/mmc would be almost a easy remember and type as /dev/sda and would be logical. But /dev/nvme0n1p2 and /dev/mmcblk0p? Why did they have to be three times as long?