# What does it mean if my system has both sda and nvme partitions?

Tags: disk

I did `lsblk` on my new dell xps and I got both sda (14G with 3 partitions) and nvme0n1 (477G with 3 partitiosn)

Does this mean my laptop has both SSD and a hard disk?

Comment: See: https://askubuntu.com/a/932336/459561 and https://superuser.com/a/1449520/628839

Comment: 14GB? Do you have a 16GB usb drive attached?

Comment: oh yes that must be it, the bootable flash drive

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filesystem shows /dev/nvme0n1p1 instead of /dev/sda](https://askubuntu.com/questions/932331/filesystem-shows-dev-nvme0n1p1-instead-of-dev-sda)