# Resize Boot Partition Next to An Extended Partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted, live-cd

I created 2 partitions:

- Boot / Root (Namely `/`).
- Home (`/home`).

I underestimated the size needed for the Boot / Root and only set it 25GB.
I now need to resize it.
I used LiveCD to run GParted and this is what I have:

[image]

Can anyone guide me how can I resize the partitions without loosing any data?
It seems I must delete the `sdf2` partition completely which means data is lost.

Is there any other way to do it (I don't have anything besides the disks above)?
On worse case scenario I don't mind losing all data on `/home` but I want the system to work as before.

Please guide me and remember those are my first steps in the Linux World.

Thank You.

Comment: Presumably resizing `sdf5` first will then allow you to resize `sdf2`, when that's done you should be able to drag the slider between them to make `sdf1` bigger at the expense of `sdf2`. Worst case, these kinds of operations can take hours or even days depending on the amount of data needing to be moved. If you can deal with it, wiping the disk and re-doing everything may be the quickest option.

Comment: @pzkpfw, No GParted won't allow doing what you're suggesting. Namely moving the beginning of `sdf5` to the right won't allow `sdf1` to get bigger (This is what I thought at first, yet it seems not trivial).

Comment: As mentioned by @pzkpfw, boot from a live CD, shrink `sdf5` by moving its left border to the right by the amount you want to grow your root partition. Then do the same with the extended partition container `sdf2` that is enclosing your home partition, so that there is no more unassigned space left inside of it. After that, you can finally grow the root partition `sdf1` by moving its right border to the right until all unpartitioned space is gone.

Comment: It shouldn't take that long though. Your home only contains few data and ext4 starts writing near the middle of a partition anyway, unlike FAT or NTFS, so probably it barely as to move any real data there. Growing should also be fairly quick. I'd assume a runtime of many minutes to few hours at most.

Comment: @ByteCommander, Would you write this as an answer?

Comment: @Royi Okay, there you go. I reused the nice screenshot from your self-answer if you don't mind.

Comment: @pzkpfw, Thank You. I +1 your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boot from a live CD to perform the partitioning operations. This is necessary because partitions can't be shrunk or moved while they are mounted. It also reduces the risk of data loss.

Also make sure that you have a backup of everything important before you start. Normally it's pretty safe, but partitioning can sometimes fail and cause data loss. Prepare yourself or continue on your own risk.

---

1. Now in GParted from the live CD, shrink `sdf5` by moving its left border to the right by the amount you want to grow your root partition.
2. Then do the same with the extended partition container `sdf2` that is enclosing your home partition, so that there is no more unassigned space left inside of it.
3. After that, you can finally grow the root partition sdf1 by moving its right border to the right until all unpartitioned space is gone.

[image: screenshot taken by Royi]

---

It shouldn't take that long though. Your home only contains few data and ext4 starts writing near the middle of a partition anyway, unlike FAT or NTFS, so probably it barely as to move any real data there. Growing should also be fairly quick. I'd assume a runtime of many minutes to few hours at most.

Comment: Perfect. I'm waiting on GParted to do its charm now. Hopefully all will be good. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I missed one crucial step that @ByteCommander noticed.
I need to resize `sdf5` partition (Drag its left boundary to the right) and then resize the *Extended Partition Container* (Colored Cyan on the screen shot and named `sdf2`) as well:

[image]

This, at least on screen, created the desired result.

@ByteCommander, please create an answer and I will mark it.

Thank You.

Comment: Do you want to keep your answer there or remove it? Feel free to suggest an edit to mine if you want to include anything additional.