# How do I resize my Ubuntu partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I have Ubuntu 14 installed and it dual boots with Windows 10. I want to extend the size of the Ubuntu partition.

I followed this article:
[How to extend my root (/) partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492054/how-to-extend-my-root-partition)

But when I swapoff my linux-swap, it says "Please unmount any logical partitions having a number higher than 5"

How do I resize now?

Here is the image:

[image: screenshot]

I have 15GB and 4.5GB unallocated. How do I extend my current Ubuntu partition?

Comment: It's not so easy in your case. You have a swap partition between the free space and your Linux partition. You can disable swap by commenting the line with swap partition in '/etc/fstab'. Than you'll be able to delete it, but it doesn't solve the problem. The easiest way to do it it's to boot from gparted livecd. You have to delete the swap partition then resize the root partition and create new swap. After that you have to correct UUID in '/etc/fstab' for your swap.

Comment: @EvgeniyYanuk please write answers in the answer section ;)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding

> Please unmount any logical partitions having a number higher than 5

Use 
a live dvd session to do this. Not the current system. You can not alter partitions that are in use unless you un-mount them and you can not un-mount an active / partition. Using a live session dvd is preferred to avoid these issues.

If you do are using a live session please un-mount the partitions by right-clicking on the launcher icon or the icon on the desktop.

Comment: Of course, you should also back up all your user data on the Windows side as well as the Linux side before you mess with partitions. This shouldn't matter, though, because you already back up your data frequently, right?

Comment: @Marc makes an excellent point that should be in most answers of this sort: Partitioning is DANGEROUS - a single miskey or mistaken click could irrecoverably DESTROY ALL YOUR DATA FOREVER. Back up all data on the entire disk before starting. Really.