# Resize partitions using Gparted

Tags: gparted, disk, partitioning

I'm trying to resize partitions of my disk with Gparted. 
I have a dual boot with Windows 10 (I would like to keep it, even if I don't use it currently) and Ubuntu.

Windows partition: 173 GiB

Ubuntu partition: 56 GiB

I would like to extend my Ubuntu partition to add around 100 GiB.

[image: Gparted screenshot]

When I'm trying to move/resize Windows partition, min size and max size are equal...

Do you have a solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extend my root (/) partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492054/how-to-extend-my-root-partition)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The picture shows exclamation marks beside the Windows NTFS partition.  You can double click on the partition to view more information about the partition and the issue.  This is commonly caused by an NTFS file system being left in an inconsistent state if it is not properly shutdown.

Try booting into Windows, and then shutdown Windows completely (not hibernate) and then try using GParted again.

Comment: But now, I can't extend my Ubuntu's partition on the left ... and I can't move the non allocated space (obtained after reducing Window's partition) on the right of my Ubuntu's partition...
Do you have an idea ? 
Thanks

Comment: Partitions that are in use (identified by the lock symbol) are limited to only a few partition editing actions.  To have full access to all the actions the partition must be unmounted.  The best way to do this is to boot from live media containing GParted, such as [GParted Live](https://gparted.org/livecd.php).