# The volume “filesystem root” has only 0 bytes disk space remaining?

Tags: 18.04

after upgrading my linux 16.04 to 18.04, one month after the volume “filesystem root” has only 0 bytes disk space remaining

```
Inspiron-5559:~$ df
Sys. de fichiers blocs de 1K   Utilisé Disponible Uti% Monté sur
udev                 3902376         0    3902376   0% /dev
tmpfs                 786532      3304     783228   1% /run
/dev/sda5           29399124  27788936      93748 100% /
tmpfs                3932644     31848    3900796   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                   5120         4       5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                3932644         0    3932644   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0             89088     89088          0 100% /snap/core/4917
/dev/loop1             35584     35584          0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/319
/dev/loop2             89984     89984          0 100% /snap/core/5548
/dev/loop3              3840      3840          0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57
/dev/loop4            375296    375296          0 100% /snap/clion/39
/dev/loop5             13312     13312          0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/117
/dev/loop6             14848     14848          0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/43
/dev/loop8             14848     14848          0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/40
/dev/loop7             14976     14976          0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/45
/dev/loop9             90112     90112          0 100% /snap/core/5328
/dev/loop10            13312     13312          0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/124
/dev/loop11           144384    144384          0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70
/dev/loop12             2304      2304          0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/238
/dev/loop13             2304      2304          0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/222
/dev/loop14            43264     43264          0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/701
/dev/loop15             3840      3840          0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/54
/dev/sda6          721521800 179801984  505045564  27% /home
tmpfs                 786528       108     786420   1% /run/user/1000
```

Some help ??

Comment: thank you for your response but couldn't fix my problem

Comment: Well, it should have at least told you which directories the space is being eaten by.  Let us know what they are and maybe we can help.

Comment: Check out the answers in this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/492054/how-to-extend-my-root-partition .
As I see, your `/home` folder has a lot of free space, you can delet some free space from it using Gparted, then assign the *new deleted* space to the `/`

Comment: I am beginner in linux, could you give to me more details please??

Answer (score 1):

Please run:

`sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean`

to remove unused packages and their cache (ther ewill be some after upgrade). from there, start with finding out what else takes a lot of space on your disk. dsstoefile1 suggested pretty good examples in his link.
there are also few helpful oneliners here:
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-find-the-largest-filesdirectories-on-a-linuxunixbsd-filesystem/

I'd start with finding & removal of old ubuntu kernels, because you don't seem to have separate `/boot` partition and those can take up to few GB on your root partition depending on how long you have your system up and running.

Comment: i did this two commandes (sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get clean),no special thing

Comment: updated my answer, please check specifically about old kernels and biggest files / directories