# Unable to merge free unallocated space with ubuntu partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted

This is the disk image. I have to merge unallocated partition of 200 GB with Ubuntu partition right next to it as I have to increase my Ubuntu size:

[image: pic1]

On right-click on `dev/sda7` partition, free space preceding is greyed out:

[image: pic2]

How do I do that?

If I do the merge, will I lose my data on Ubuntu or windows?

Comment: @Pilot6 please explain in simple steps for this specific problem as my free space is in left to ubuntu and on clicking resize/move unable to move left for dev/sda7

Comment: Boot from a LiveUSB, you can't modify `/` from inside a working system.

Comment: is this the only way? that way i will loose my data and all the settings?

Comment: Why would you lose the data?

Comment: what does boot from a LiveUSB mean then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105290/discussion-between-y-159-and-pilot6).

Comment: It means insert a LiveUSB drive to a USB port and boot from it choosing "Try Ubuntu". Also beware that resizing `/` to the left will require updating grub using `chroot`. If you don't understand this, then you need to get some knowledge first.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/492054/how-to-extend-my-root-partition

Comment: thanks i will read throught it first.  will ask if any problem still ocurrs.

Comment: You always want to have good backups. That way if any mistake or system error occurs you have a fallback. And changes to system configuration require you to refresh you backup, just in case. You will have to move partition left & expand right. Do not interrupt process and best not to queue them, but run each separately. If you interrupt it for any reason, even power failure you will will corrupt data, or why you have to have good backups. Did I mention you should have backups? :)

Comment: Here's how I solved it?  initially, I mounted that 200GB free space on ubuntu partition. Then after some time i came to know about another solution, I formatted the free space to copy the Ubuntu partition data to this 200GB space. and checked it by booting ubuntu from that partition. then i deleted the previously existing Ubuntu partition and extended this new ubuntu partition to have more space. everything worked well.