# Tab autocomplete in bash does not work for directories but does work for programs Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: command-line, 16.04, bash, auto-completion

I'm getting the same message each time I try and [TAB] to autocomplete into a directory:
`test` being the directory within `var/www/html`

```
# hitting [TAB] after typing 'test'
$ ll test-bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device
-bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device
```

Errow with `ll`, `cat`, `cd` and [TAB]

I can use autocomplete with `vim`

```
$ vim test/testing.html
```

I read a few posts about this but could not solve my problem. The last thing I did was run:

```
sudo apt install bash-completion
```

At the bottom of my `~/.bashrc` I have:

```
# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
#if ! shopt -oq posix; then
#  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
#    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
#  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
#    . /etc/bash_completion
#  fi
#fi
source /etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh
```

With `/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh` as:

```
# /etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh
# Check for interactive bash and that we haven't already been sourced.
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" -a -n "$PS1" -a -z "$BASH_COMPLETION_COMPAT_DIR" ]; then

# Check for recent enough version of bash.
bash=${BASH_VERSION%.*}; bmajor=${bash%.*}; bminor=${bash#*.}
if [ $bmajor -gt 4 ] || [ $bmajor -eq 4 -a $bminor -ge 1 ]; then
    [ -r "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config}/bash_completion" ] && \
        . "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config}/bash_completion"
    if shopt -q progcomp && [ -r /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
        # Source completion code.
        . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
    fi
fi
unset bash bmajor bminor

fi
```

Any suggestions would be great. It easy to feel how much I autocomplete in bash. `$ which bash
/bin/bash`

Thanks
Dave

UPDATE: I ran `df` and it looks like the problem?

```
$ df
Filesystem                      1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev                              8196256       0   8196256   0% /dev
tmpfs                             1643260   33636   1609624   3% /run
/dev/mapper/vg-root               3566896 3366004         0 100% /
tmpfs                             8216288       0   8216288   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                             8216288       0   8216288   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                          482922  267633    190355  59% /boot
tmpfs                             1643260       0   1643260   0% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: bash-completions require that you have free space in root `/` file system. Free up some space or [extend the partition and file system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492054/how-to-extend-my-root-partition)

Comment: I added the output from `df` to my post and that must be it. i'm going to contact the client vendor and ask. my virtual machine has `40636768` vs `3566896` seems small?

Comment: Yes, you have 0 Available blocks on your root `/` Mount.

Comment: The amount of space seems large if I have not put any files up on the server yet. I've only updated Apache and PHP-FPM. This seems odd, yes? If it's a 1k-block and there are 3566896 that's 3.5 gb available and used.

Answer (score 0):

@thomas-ward
Since my previous answer was changed to comments and I don't have the rep to add a comment, I'll just add another answer and leave it to you to change. Sorry.

@kaplan
Looking at the root file system line of `df`

```
Filesystem                      1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg-root               3566896 3366004         0 100% /
```

The **Available** block count is **0**. This is the free space for files on the volume.

**3566896** is the **1k-blocks** count which is the total size of the volume (used + free + reserved)