# Where is my free space gone?

Tags: 18.04, disk-usage, hyper-v

I am very new to Ubuntu. I just set up a Hyper V installation on my Windows laptop, and gave it a 30GB hard drive space.

I got a notification that my root drive is almost full. According to the screenshot below I only have 12GB, almost at maximum capacity. I know the Ubunutu installation itself takes up some space, but 18GB is missing. Any ideas?

[image]

I've read some similar posts here, for example, somebody had to post the output of `df -h --total` . So here it is, in case it helps:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           595M  1.4M  594M   1% /run
/dev/sda1        12G   11G  725M  94% /
tmpfs           3.0G   42M  2.9G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.0G     0  3.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1      3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/100
/dev/loop4       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1074
/dev/loop3       43M   43M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1313
/dev/loop0      150M  150M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/71
/dev/loop2      1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/61
/dev/loop5       15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/296
/dev/loop6      4.2M  4.2M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/406
/dev/loop7       89M   89M     0 100% /snap/core/7396
/dev/sda15      105M  3.6M  101M   4% /boot/efi
tmpfs           595M   16K  595M   1% /run/user/121
tmpfs           595M   52K  595M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop8       68M   68M     0 100% /snap/sublime-text/85
/dev/loop9       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1754
/dev/loop10      97M   97M     0 100% /snap/core/9436
/dev/loop11     1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/100
/dev/loop12     384K  384K     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/550
/dev/loop13     2.3M  2.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/148
/dev/loop14     2.5M  2.5M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/748
/dev/loop15     162M  162M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/128
/dev/loop16      63M   63M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
/dev/loop17     256M  256M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36
total            24G   12G   12G  52% -
```

I am not 100% sure what to do with this, it just confirms my problem. The `Avail` column says that there are 12GB available somewhere. Is this 12GB locked up in the system somewhere?

edit: Output of `lsblk`:

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0     7:0    0 149.9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/71
loop1     7:1    0   3.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/100
loop2     7:2    0  1008K  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/61
loop3     7:3    0  42.8M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1313
loop4     7:4    0  54.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/1074
loop5     7:5    0  14.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/296
loop6     7:6    0     4M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/406
loop7     7:7    0  88.7M  1 loop /snap/core/7396
loop8     7:8    0  67.6M  1 loop /snap/sublime-text/85
loop9     7:9    0    55M  1 loop /snap/core18/1754
loop10    7:10   0  96.5M  1 loop /snap/core/9436
loop11    7:11   0   956K  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/100
loop12    7:12   0   276K  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/550
loop13    7:13   0   2.2M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/148
loop14    7:14   0   2.4M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/748
loop15    7:15   0 161.4M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/128
loop16    7:16   0  62.1M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
loop17    7:17   0 255.6M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36
sda       8:0    0    30G  0 disk 
├─sda1    8:1    0  11.9G  0 part /
├─sda14   8:14   0     4M  0 part 
└─sda15   8:15   0   106M  0 part /boot/efi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got unused disk space. it's like having a 100G disk with a single 10G NTFS partition.

Your whole disk size is 30G. Your main partition is `/dev/sda1` where Ubuntu has been installed on which is 12G.

You can create a new partition from your unused disk space and use it as your home to free-up some space. Or use partitioning tools like gparted to [resize your root partition size](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492054/how-to-extend-my-root-partition).

```
sda       8:0    0    30G  0 disk     <---- Your virtual DISK
├─sda1    8:1    0  11.9G  0 part /   <---- Your first partition where ubuntu
├                                           is installed. (12G)
├─sda14   8:14   0     4M  0 part 
└─sda15   8:15   0   106M  0 part /boot/efi
```

Comment: You may use `resize2fs` -->  `sudo resize2fs -p /dev/sda1`