# Merge root partition with unallocated space

Tags: 18.04, gparted, root, swap, resize

The root partition space in my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is almost exhausted, so I want to extend this partition. This is a picture from :[Gparted output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blLOF.png). I want to merge the `/dev/sda8` partition with the unallocated space preceding it. I used `sudo resize2fs /dev/sda8`, and it gave

```
resize2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
The filesystem is already 4941312 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

I was following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492054/how-to-extend-my-root-partition) link. But it is not working. Is there any way of achieving what I want to do without using a live Gparted session? And also, is it absolutely necessary to have swap space adjacent to `/`?

Comment: Need to do it from a live USB with the partitions unmounted.  This can cause lost of data, so backups are important.  You have more free space with your sda4 partition, that I would use to install Ubuntu onto.  Will need to enlarge your /home partition soon also.

Comment: Any time you mess with partitions there's ALWAYS a risk of data loss!  Looking at your pic there it appears that you would have to move sda8 to before the unallocated space in order for you to add the 9GB to it.  Gparted may not allow you to move it when the partition is mounted so you probably would be looking at doing the moving from a Live USB.  Also, the swap doesn't need to be adjacent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an amateur, but after having used gparted about 200times in the past 20 years i noticed that you don't have a swap partition instead. I always made a swap partition in between before i started to install anything. I wonder where these 9.82 GiBs unallocated came from, i always had about a few MiBs only in between. Also i noticed that you seem to have a 64-Bit-PC with an EFI partition. In 3rd i noticed that the other mentioned one by link had an extended Partition with the flag lba. - PS: I never found out if that flag is necessary or not. Wkr, P.

Comment: I got that 9GB unallocated space by deleting the linux-swap space

Comment: Is it possible to reduce the size of the /dev/sda4 partition, of course after defragmenting under Windows ? Would that make sense ?