# How to extend EXT Partition of Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, ext4

I've Dual booted Ubuntu in PC by shrinking the C: drive
actual size of c: drive ntfs is 100 GB and Ext partition is 15 Gb now I'm thinking to extend the size of EXT where Ubuntu is installed without Shrinking the C: drive Because My C: Drive is completely Full . I've tried to shrink the remaining Drives like E,F.... but they unallocated spaces is accessable while extending Ext of Ubuntu ..

Please Help

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of GParted? I guess you mean you can't use the unallocated space because there's still a partition between your Ubuntu partition and the unallocated space?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I increase a partition's size?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/102733/how-can-i-increase-a-partitions-size)

Comment: I don't understand neither the current situation nor what you're trying to achieve. Could you please clarify. Maybe include a screenshot of GParted for illustration.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method would be to use Ubuntu on a Live CD/DVD/USB (so that you aren't using any of your hoard drive partitions) and then repartition your drive in GParted.

Note that the concept of "C drive", "D drive", etc. is within Windows only, and you won't see such lettering in GParted. You'll have to know the approximate size and (relative) positions of your partitions so that you can identify which is which.