# gparted - extending into linux swap

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

My desktop has Windows and Ubuntu in dual boot. Overall, I have a 500GB SDD. It turns out I have managed to limit my Ubuntu installation to a tiny 24 GB portion of it. I have only realised this when Ubuntu started warning me that I had run out of space (!).

I was looking at links [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102733/how-can-i-increase-a-partitions-size) and [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions) on how I can increase my Ubuntu partition. The links suggest installing and running gparted and then resizing. However, when I run gparted, I am confused as to how I can do the resizing. I am attaching a screen shot below:

[image]

My questions are:

**1)** Some links suggest booting from a live CD. Is this necessary or can I do the resizing by simply running Gparted on Ubuntu.?

**2)** From its size (24 GB) and from it being completely yellow (full), I believe my Linux partition is on /dev/sda5. I can see sda6 right next to it, which is virtually empty. However it is a brown color and its file system is linux-swap. There is an option to 'swapoff'. Am I supposed to do this? When I right click on sda5, I cannot select a new size.

**3)** There is a further /dev/sda3 partition to the left of these two. It seems completely empty. How can I merge this with /sda4 and /sda5 and allocate all to my Ubuntu setup?

I will be grateful for any pointers.

Comment: Just as a note, you cannot resize any partition with gparted that is mounted.  You can tell which ones are by the key right after the name.  Best to do this from a LiveCD.

Comment: You do not need 32GB of swap. If you have 4GB or more of RAM you can make swap be 2 or 3GB unless you want to hibernate. If you want to use sda3 either delete or shrink it. Move extended partition left so unallocated is then inside extended. I do not like moving partitions left. You move left & expand right in two steps. Process each step on its own. Any interruption during move totally corrupts it so have good backups and do not interrupt move.

Comment: @oldfred, thank you. how do I reduce the swap? do I right click an select 'Swapoff'? Also, as Terrance said, do I need to 'unmount' everything before I can move stuff around? Currently all my partitions have key symbols to their right. Resize/Move is option is not avialable when I right click onthe swap partition.

Comment: Even live installer mounts swap to speed install/use. So yes you have to swap off or unmount swap. And any mounted logical partition inside extended also mounts the extended. Since you cannot unmount / you have to use live installer.