# Extending linux partitiion

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, budgie

I realised that I may need more space for Linux as kind it is shifting towards being my primary workspace, hence I decided to extend its size. I un-alloacated a chunk of memory from windows'( [these are my partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZ5XR.png) ) partition and tried merging it to the Linux's but I could not.
I am using **Gparted**. My OS is **Ununtu Budgie**. Attached is a screenshot of my partitions.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/102733/how-can-i-increase-a-partitions-size

Comment: The little key icons show you have mounted partitions, you need to use live installer. A move left can be slow as it has to copy all data, do not interrupt. Then resize to right to make it larger is very quick. With a move, you must have good backups, any interruption will totally corrupt data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or lose data.

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a **swapoff** on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a **swapon** on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- start `gparted`
- **move** /dev/nvme0n1p6 partition all the way left
- **resize** the right side of /dev/nvme0n1p6 all the way right
- click the Apply icon